# Negation of For all $p/q$ there exists $K$ such that $|\alpha -p/q|\le K/q^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

What is the negation of the following statement :

> *For all $p/q$ there exists $K$ such that $|\alpha -p/q|\le K/q^n$*.

I'm thinking that *For all $p/q$ and for all $K$, |$\alpha -p/q|>K/q^n$*.

Am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $\neg (\forall x P(x))\equiv \exists x \neg P(x)$ and $\neg (\exists x P(x))\equiv \forall x \neg P(x))$.

Let's do it step by step.

$\neg$ ($\forall p/q$  ($\exists K$ such that $|α−p/q|≤K/q^n$))$\equiv$

$\exists p/q$ such that $\neg$ ( $\exists K$ such that $|α−p/q|≤K/q^n$))$\equiv$

$\exists p/q$ such that $\forall K$ $\neg (|α−p/q|≤K/q^n))\equiv$

$\exists p/q$ such that $\forall K$ $|α−p/q|>K/q^n$.

In english, there exists $p/q$  such that for all $K$, $|α−p/q|>K/q^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if wrong :

1) There exists a $p/q$ such that for all $K$

the statement $|\alpha - p/q| \le K/q^n$ is not true.

Hence:

2) There exists a $p/q$ such that for all $K$

$|\alpha -p/q| > K/q^n.$